# Dividing columns of a matrix by elements of a vector

Tags: r

I am figuring out how to divide the nth column of a matrix by the nth element of a row vector.

For example, let matrix a and vector b be:

```
a <- matrix(1:9, byrow = TRUE,  nrow = 3)
b <- c(3:5)
```

giving

```
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    7    8    9

[[2]]
[1] 3 4 5
```

In this case, I'm looking for code that divides the first column of the matrix by 3, second by 4 and the thrird by 5.

I have tried using the apply function with no success

```
c <- apply(a, 2, function(x) x / b)
```

Is there any code that can do this with apply and preferably without using loops?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use `sweep` for this:

```
#same as apply the second argument needs to be 1 for row or 2 for column
sweep(a, 2, b, FUN = '/')
#          [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,] 0.3333333 0.50  0.6
#[2,] 1.3333333 1.25  1.2
#[3,] 2.3333333 2.00  1.8
```

Answer (score 6):

You can take the transpose of the matrix, divide, and transpose again the result.

```
t(t(a)/b)
#          [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,] 0.3333333 0.50  0.6
#[2,] 1.3333333 1.25  1.2
#[3,] 2.3333333 2.00  1.8
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option is `mapply`, i.e.

```
mapply(`/`, data.frame(a), b)
```

which gives

> ```
>            X1   X2  X3
> [1,] 0.3333333 0.50 0.6
> [2,] 1.3333333 1.25 1.2
> [3,] 2.3333333 2.00 1.8
> ```